# DNN 7 Installation and folder permissions

Tags: dotnetnuke, folder-permissions

I'm trying to install DNN 7 on my computer.

I'm actuallt at the point where I need to set permissions to my wwwroot folder.

I've already set permissions to
    IUSR
    ISS_IUSRS
    DefaultAppPool
    PCname\Administrateurs

But when I go to IIS manager, and test my parameters, I got

```
Impossible to verify access to folder D:\web\devel\wwwroot
```

And when I'm trying to access to localhost, I got a white page, blank, and console give me a 500 error.

I've searched a lot, but I didn't found any solution which help me for that problem.

Did you got any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chech the AppPool's identity and see who it is ... that is what you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to set permissions based on the ACCOUNT that the Application Pool is running in IIS. Check which user account is being used by the Pool and setup permissions for that user.

Comment: I'm not 100%sure, but I think I already did that when i added DefaultAppPool as user.
And anonyme authentification are set to Application Pool identity.